# TypeScript - Switch Statement based on Enum Comparison goes straight to DefaultCase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums

**THE PROBLEM:**
I have a switch Statement. The comparison is based on two `enums`. But the conditions are all returning false.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION FOUND ON STACK_OVERFLOW:**
I read somewhere, that in order to avoid this, you have to put a `+` in the case like so:

```
switch(+resources) instead of switch(resources)
```

This has the side effect, of transforming the `case` in a number, which makes TS, quite unhappy since my `enums` are `strings`.

**SAMPLE CODE:**
The enums, I want to use in my Function:

```
enum ResourceTypes {
  RESOURCE1 = 'RESOURCE1',
  RESOURCE2 = 'RESOURCE2',
  RESOURCE3 = 'RESOURCE2',
}

export default ResourceTypes;
```

```
enum OperationTypes {
  OPERATION1 = 'OPERATION1',
  OPERATION2 = 'OPERATION2',
  OPERATION3 = 'OPERATION3',
  OPERATION4 = 'OPERATION4'
}

export default OperationTypes;
```

The Function, that reverts always to the default case, is simply checking the `resourceType`, and returns an array of operations:

```
import ResourceTypes from '../enums/ResourceTypes';
import OperationTypes from '../enums/OperationTypes';

const operationPerResource = (resource: any): OperationTypes[] => {
  const { RESOURCE1, RESOURCE2, RESOURCE3 } = ResourceTypes;
  const { OPERATION1, OPERATION2, OPERATION3, OPERATION4 } = OperationTypes;

  switch (resource) {
    case RESOURCE1:
      return [OPERATION2, OPERATION3, OPERATION4];
    case RESOURCE2:
      return [OPERATION1, OPERATION2, OPERATION3];
    case RESOURCE3:
      return [OPERATION1, OPERATION2];
    default:
      return [];
  }
};

export default operationPerResource;
```

And this is where I call the function:

```
    const resources = transformEnumToArray(ResourceTypes);

    const operations = operationPerResource(resources.value).map((value: any) => ({
      label: value,
      value
    }));
```

This is the transofrmEnumToArray Function:

```
const transformEnumToArray = (object: object): any =>
  Object.keys(object).map(value => ({
    label: value,
    value
  }));

export default transformEnumToArray;
```

A few details on the implementation. `operations` is used in a React-Select Component. So, for every selection, I make on one field(Resources), I get the available Operations in another.

The resources.value, is printed in the console. I get everything back , in a `label, value` object, as per every react-select.

---

I mean, what am I doing wrong here? Why is the comparison for the enums, aren't working. Can you guys help me out here? I tested this with `constants` instead of enums and it works just fine. So what is the difference with `enums` in Typescript? **Thank you**

Comment: You have a typo here `RESOURCE3 = 'RESOURCE2'` other than that it seems to work, could you show how you call the function

Comment: Testing the above code in official typescript playground and jsfiddle with version 3.5.1 it works as intended, can you please give a reproducible example? https://jsfiddle.net/ab9v8mty/

Comment: Sounds like `(resource: any)` isn't what you're hoping it should be (the `any` sounds like a bad idea here)

Comment: Well, `resource:any`, is a small update that I can easily fix. Already done it, but doesn't change the outcome. I have updated the question, with the way I use the function, and where I get the data, with the appropriate tranformation function as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `switch` expression in a function with typed parameter, this works as expected.

Example:

```
enum ResourceTypes {
    RESOURCE1 = 'RESOURCE1',
    RESOURCE2 = 'RESOURCE2',
    RESOURCE3 = 'RESOURCE2',
}

enum OperationTypes {
    OPERATION1 = 'OPERATION1',
    OPERATION2 = 'OPERATION2',
    OPERATION3 = 'OPERATION3',
    OPERATION4 = 'OPERATION4',
}

const operationPerResource = (resource: ResourceTypes): OperationTypes[] => {
    const { RESOURCE1, RESOURCE2, RESOURCE3 } = ResourceTypes;
    const { OPERATION1, OPERATION2, OPERATION3, OPERATION4 } = OperationTypes;

    switch (resource) {
        case RESOURCE1:
            return [OPERATION2, OPERATION3, OPERATION4];
        case RESOURCE2:
            return [OPERATION1, OPERATION2, OPERATION3];
        case RESOURCE3:
            return [OPERATION1, OPERATION2];
        default:
            return [];
    }
};


console.log (operationPerResource(ResourceTypes.RESOURCE2))
```

will compile  and output `["OPERATION1", "OPERATION2", "OPERATION3"]`

Answer (score 0):

Can you show example calling code? A few thoughts that might help to track down the issue:

I would expect the signature to be

```js
const operationPerResource = (resource: ResourceType): OperationTypes[]
```

This will guarantee you're calling with a ResourceType

I've never seen enums destructured like that. Of course I don't think there's anything wrong with it, but it's possible that TypeScript is doing something unexpected with the types. Does anything change if you rewrite out explicitly `ResourceType.RESOURCE1`, etc.

Comment: I didn't try it to tell you the truth. But `babel` in the end, should transform them in the correct structure. Let me try it and get back to you..

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work out. Destructuring shouldn't have played the role anyway. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Now that you've posted the calling code, it's pretty clear why you needed to type the signature as `any` - it does not seem like you're calling the code with a ResourceType 'RESOURCE1'

In general, avoid using `any` in TypeScript, it's a cop-out that hides bad types

Try putting a log statement inside of the operationPerResource function, I bet you do not see something like

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
(I can't comment your post yet)

If you check in typescript playground you can see why it works with JS object dans not enum.
When you check `RESOURCE1` it's not evaluated as the string `RESOURCE1` you chan check that by changing `RESOURCE1: 'RESOURCE123'` for exemple

I don't usually work with enum neither but seems that

```
const { RESOURCE1, RESOURCE2, RESOURCE3 } = ResourceTypes

// RESOURCE1 != 'RESOURCE1' as it would be for a JS Object
// RESOURCE1 === RESOURCE1
```

You can check [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBASsDOB7MAnAxsAKgTwA4KgG8AoKWAUQGUB5AVRgGFyBGKAXigHIYq7GWAhgC9gnADSkKNekwBM7Lj2n9Z4yUr5MAzAu68Z5VRIC+xYqEhRq+FAIAuAS0Qgc+eEUnUACuRgBBTABJagA5Vg5Ob18A4LC1Mij-IND5CMSYlPirHyTYnTScjJCtLPTkkIAWXTLYis5iU2I0Z3g7IilNFjEOg1lujQMdYwU4JFQMVwQmlrbCbOjy5m6alOXC8q01hdqoYY5rYFtHZ0n4M2aQVqg0AXgCDhIyAf5mAC4oAG0VkL753NDNn8ihUALoSJ76FTvL7rWJLIHlX7fLRg9SQ7TQ77w76yVFkAAmwAAZgIwAAbOzQkENaaXRBk4AAOjJiAA5gAKG53eAASmIQA) open your console, and hit run button.
If you look at cases keys, you'll see that the first one is not `RESOURCE1aze` but still `RESOURCE1`

---

You could still use tell don't ask pattern to avoid switch statement :

```js
import { RESOURCE1, RESOURCE2, RESOURCE3 } from '../enums/ResourceTypes'
import { OPERATION1, OPERATION2, OPERATION3, OPERATION4 } from '../enums/OperationTypes'

const cases = {
  RESOURCE1: [OPERATION2, OPERATION3, OPERATION4],
  RESOURCE2: [OPERATION1, OPERATION2, OPERATION3],
  RESOURCE3: [OPERATION1, OPERATION2],
  default: []
}

const operationPerResource = (resource: ResourceTypes): OperationTypes[] => {
  const operations = cases[ressource] || cases['default']
  return operations
}

export default operationPerResource
```

Here is [an exemple in the typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBASsDOB7MAnAxsAKgTwA4KgG8AoKWAUQGUB5AVRgGFyBGKAXigHIYq7GXOAGlIUa9JgCZ2XHmP4ShI2XyYBmad17jyC4QF9ixUJCjV8KAIYAXAJaIQOfPCIjqABXIwAgpgCS1ADlWDk53Tx9-IMUyMO8-QKkQ2IiE6NMPOMj1JIyUgNU05PiAgBYNIsiSzmIDYjR7eCsiURUWQRbtCXblbXU9aTgkVAxHBDqGpsJ08OLmdoqE+dzi1SWZyqh+jjNgS1t7UfhDepBGqDQLeAIOEjIe-mYALigAbQWArunMwNWvvJKALrCO5aeTPN7LSJzP7FT7vVRApSgtTg97Q94SRFkAAmwAAZhYwAAbKzggE1Y4TKCIczWOwgNy7QbIdDAaQAChQCBZGGezOGWDwCAAlM8dnt6YcXgD2AA+FxkE5nGm7OkNaQXK7wF5coasmUAHwN50uCBenFxBOJVk45LIXKsqBA1Np+1OFPGp0QROAADoiYgAObslUS+yMlD81nsqMjIXwX33JjMYXCoA)